# How to calculate constant GDP in international $ from nominal GDP in local currency units

Tags: gdp, purchasing-power-partity, price-index

I want to calculate a constant GDP serie from 1995 till 2014 based on nominal GDP expressed in Yuan (Chinese currency).

I already get stuck on how to first make a constant GDP serie based on Yuan, let alone on international dollars.

Would it be enough to use the GDP deflator with base year 2014 to get constant GDP series in Yuan in 2014 prices?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use PPP rates. These convert basket of goods in one country (in LCU) to that of (normally) the US, in US dollars. You can find these rates [here](http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/PA.NUS.PPP) or [here](https://data.oecd.org/conversion/purchasing-power-parities-ppp.htm). With these rates you can transform nominal GDP in Yuan into nominal GDP in USD. Then, you can use a US CPI or GDP deflator index to transform these nominal international dollars into constant international dollars. The base year is given by the price index you use.

You can rear more about PPP and how to use it [here](http://www.oecd.org/std/47359870.pdf).

Finally, in case you do not want to bother to calculate this yourself, or that you want to confirm your calculations, [here](http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/NY.GDP.MKTP.PP.KD?locations=CN) is the actual series of China's GDP in 2011 international dollars.